# Pinch to zoom in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, touchscreen, zoom

I'm having a strange issue in Firefox. My new computer (surface book) has a touchscreen and I really like the feature of zooming in by making the "pinch" gesture on the screen. In Chrome and Edge, this works how I'd expect it to. It "zooms" in. If I zoom in via the zoom buttons it makes all the text bigger in the traditional scrolling style. This is, however, not the case in Firefox. Firefox adjusts the browser's "zoom level" (which is really scaling, not zooming, in my option) and is not the result I want.

The question:

Is there any way to get Firefox to actually zoom in with a touchscreen pinch gesture instead of just magnifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it's been a while (two years!) and Firefox still hasn't fixed this issue but I've found a workaround in the form of this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-touch-zoom/

It does exactly what I want!

Funny thing, this exact bug has been known for around 6 years now and not fixed! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789906

Answer (score 6):

### Update

Native support has [landed in 83.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/83.0/releasenotes/).

It now works well with **history navigation**, placement of **context menus** and web content like **Wikipedia article previews**.

What's not done yet?

- Scrollable content within a zoomed-in page works, but still has twitchy scroll bars.
- Double-tapping with two fingers to zoom in on a specific column of text
- Unifying the pinch zoom with the auto-resize feature to fit an image to the window, and with the content zoom [ + | 100% | - ] toolbar buttons when viewing a single non-vector image. In other words, the visible part of the image does not rerender when pinch-zooming in on an image that is not drawn in full resolution.

---

I don't know if this also works for touchscreens, but this **finally works natively** for me on a Macbook Air touchpad. No more need for CSS wizardry from extensions (I also used [Multi-touch Zoom](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-touch-zoom/) up until now, so thanks to the author).

Set `apz.allow_zooming` to `true` on the `about:config` page in Firefox Nightly 71.0a1.

I don't know for how long this option has been available, but I found it just now by following the trail from [688990](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688990) and ending up applying the steps to reproduce (STR) in [1556556](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1556556).

Scroll behavior is not perfect while zoomed in, but I think it's still worth it in order to reduce the layout problems that could result from using the extension on some webpages (e.g. Reddit). Zoom out, reposition the cursor and zoom in again is an acceptable workaround until the feature lands.

The responsiveness is also hugely improved compared to the extension. There is no more delay between the pinch and the zoom, and it's now also possible to initiate a pinch while the page is scrolling, which saves time from first having to stop the inertial scrolling -- something that was always necessary with the extension.

**Update**
I should add that I didn't quite understand the difference between "zooming", "magnifying" and "scaling" in your question (to me they're all pretty much synonymous), or what you meant by "traditional scrolling style". I'm just assuming that I'm answering your question based on the fact that the Multi-touch Zoom extension solved your problem.

Comment: Note for anyone looking to enable this flag. The reason this is disabled by default is because the feature is fairly buggy as of April 2020. The interaction between the zoomed page and context menu (right-click dropdown), color picker, etc. is very janky. BUT, for most common cases it works just fine, and the bugs were bearable, so I turned it on.